# Use a "for" to include different file extensions

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

This is the whole script but I'm just interested in modifying the following line:

```
for /R %%x in (*.jpg)
```

I want to include also *.png and *.gif

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\"Program Files"\FileOptimizer
Set /A "threads=8,i=0"
:: initialize List
For /L %%n in (1,1,%threads%) Do Set "List%%n="

for /R %%x in (*.jpg) do  ( 
  Set /A "n=i %% threads + 1,i+=1"
  call set "LIST!n!=%%LIST!n!%% "%%x""
)

For /L %%n in (1,1,%threads%) Do (
    echo list: !LIST%%n!
    START FileOptimizer64.exe !LIST%%n!
    )
```

Comment: `in (*.jpg *.png *.gif) do`

Comment: This is *not* DOS. DOS doesn't have a "Program Files" directory, nor can it run 64-bit code, nor is it multi-threaded, nor… on and on. Don't tag your questions [dos] if they're actually about running batch files on Windows.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: ...from the help of [`for /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html): *»(set)      Specifies a set of **one or more files**.  Wildcards may be used.«*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /R %%x in (*.jpg,*.png,*.gif)
```

That's it.